# R - multiple actions after the if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

My question is how to put in multiple actions after the if statement. For example:

```
vartest <- var.test(var1 ~ group, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, data=data1)
ttest <- t.test(var1~group, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, var.equal=FALSE, data=data1)
if (vartest$p.value>0.05) {
  if (ttest$p.value<=0.05) {
    cat(ttest$p.value)
    ggboxplot(data1, x="group", y="var1", color="group", palette=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), ylab="var1", xlab="group")
    group_by(data1, group) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(var1, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(var1, na.rm = TRUE))
  } else{
    cat("text1.")
    }
} else{
  cat("text2.")
  }
```

It isn't giving me my desired result, instead only the first and the last part of the expressions was printed to the console.
If I change the order of the actions for that:

```
vartest <- var.test(var1 ~ group, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, data=data1)
ttest <- t.test(var1~group, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, var.equal=FALSE, data=data1)
if (vartest$p.value>0.05) {
  if (ttest$p.value<=0.05) {
    cat(ttest$p.value)
    group_by(data1, group) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(var1, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(var1, na.rm = TRUE))
    ggboxplot(data1, x="group", y="var1", color="group", palette=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), ylab="var1", xlab="group")
  } else{
    cat("text1.")
    }
} else{
  cat("text2.")
  }
```

Only the first and the last part of the expressions are printed to the console.

Any ideas how can I run all actions between if and else?
Please help!

Comment: Please add reproducible data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the data you're working with, but I recreated your problem as follows:

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p.value <- 0.02

if (p.value<=0.05) {
    cat(p.value)
    mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(hp))
    qplot(x = wt, y = mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "point")
} else{
    cat("text1.")
}
```

The example above will only print `p.value` and the plot. Switching the order of the plot and the summary table will return only the p.value and summary table.

To solve this, we can assign back and explicitly print.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p.value <- 0.02

if (p.value<=0.05) {
    cat(p.value)
    my_sum <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(hp))
    print(my_sum)
    my_plot <- qplot(x = wt, y = mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "point")
    print(my_plot)
} else{
    cat("text1.")
}
```

Comment: You don't need to assign if you don't want to. `mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(count = n(), mean = mean(hp)) %>% print()` is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit printing is disabled inside braces, and the value of the last expression is returned.

```
{
    "hello"
    cat("world\n")
    "how are you"
    "today?"
}

## world
## [1] "today?"
```

If you want to print or otherwise display something from inside braces you can use explicit `print`, or `message` or `cat`.

```
{
    print("hello")
    cat("world\n")
    message("how are you")
    "today?"
}
## [1] "hello"
## world
## how are you
## [1] "today?"
```